# Converting EMA and ATR logic to Psuedocode

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to understand the following piece of pinescript and turn it into pseudocode to replicate it. The entire script is in the url mentioned at the end but here are the most important bits:

```
changeATR= true
atr2 = sma(tr, Periods)
atr= changeATR ? atr(Periods) : atr2
movAvg=EMA(hl2, 10)
lngStop = movAvg - 3*ATR(10)
lngStopPrev = nz(lngStop[1], lngStop)
lngStop := movAvg > lngStopPrev ? max(lngStop, lngStopPrev) : lngStop
shrtStop = Normalize ? MAvg + Multiplier*atr/close : MAvg + Multiplier*atr
shrtStopPrev = nz(shrtStop[1], shrtStop)
shrtStop := MAvg < shrtStopPrev ? min(shrtStop, shrtStopPrev) : shrtStop

dir = 1
dir := nz(dir[1], dir)
dir := dir == -1 and movAvg > shrtStopPrev ? 1 : dir == 1 and movAvg < lngStopPrev ? -1 : dir
pMx = dir==1 ? lngStop: shrtStop
alertcondition(crossover(movAvg, pMx), title="Crossover", message="Moving Avg BUY!")
```

I have attempted to do the following but I don't think it is correct.

```
Latest "ema(  "(  high +  low ) / 2" , 10 )" crossed_above Latest "1 candle ago  ""ema(  "(  high +  low ) / 2" , 10)" - 3 *  avg true range( 10 )""
```

I even tried this:

```
Latest "ema(  "(  high +  low ) / 2" , 10 )" crossed_above Latest ""ema(  "(  high +  low ) / 2" , 10 )" - 3 *  "sma(  true range( 14 ) , 10 )" /  close"
```

Unfortunately I do not have a result to compare it to but if anyone can point out where am I going wrong, it would be very helpful.

Here's the original script https://www.tradingview.com/script/sU9molfV/

Comment: Is there a built-in function or variable that you don't understand?

Comment: I have given two psuedo logic based on my understanding. Does it look ok?